# Lug nut not fitting steel rim holes?

Tags: wheels, safety, lug-nut

I recently purchased a second set of rims for my car, a 2009 Kia Cee'd SW (ED). This is a set of steel rims, and as the other one are not, they had a different type of lug nuts than normal.

So the shop I went to had one kind of lug nuts at hand specced for the car, and fitted one wheel, but it looked like in the picture, so I asked to put the old one back for now to have a second opinion. Seemed solid and non-wiggly, but the contacting surface is somewhat smaller than I'd be comfortable with.

Is this safe? Is it even the right lug nut for the rim? The spec was M12/1.5 for the lug nut.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the cone on the lug nut matches the cone in the rim then it will be fine when tightened to the correct torque.

The lug nuts that would fit that "closer" will still have the same cone but won't have the shoulder shown so they would be smaller.

Some nuts are designed to have a flat head to work for alloy rims while the cone is for steel rims, but other manufacturers supply two types of lug nut (as does my car maker).